# Shell command to find files in a directory pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell, console

With a shell command i need to list all files on my server in the following directory pattern:

> /home/*/public_html/images/*.php

Theres a few an its taking a long time to do this manually. I really have no idea when it comes to these commands.

Comment: Yes. That's the correct syntax. Does it not work? Or do you want to make it faster? If so, there's no inherent optimization possible. Just alternatives and workarounds. `locate|grep` being one for searching cached directory listings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Shell Script:

```
find /home/*/public_html/images -iname "*php" -exec echo {} \;
```

You can then change the -exec command to do whatever actions you want to the returned files.  In this case, we echo them, but you could easily perform other actions as well.

Comment: This will match `/home/foo/public_html/images/file.php` but not `/home/foo/bar/public_html/images/file.php`. Any way I could match directories at any depth?

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer below, using `-path` matches directories at any depth.  (E.g., `-path "*/images/*" would match any files in any path that has an `images` directory.)

Answer (score 37):

```
find /path/to/directory/.  -path "*/match/this/path/*" -type f -name "*.php"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. It finds files in `/path/to/directory/foo/match/this/path` and `/path/to/directory/foo/bar/match/this/path/baz/`

Answer (score 5):

Let bash expand the files for you and use `ls` to list them:

```
ls /home/*/public_html/images/*.php
```

Example output:

```
/home/grant/public_html/images/bar.php
/home/grant/public_html/images/foo.php
/home/marcog/public_html/images/helloworld.php
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the PHP [glob](http://php.net/glob) function

```
glob('/home/*/public_html/images/*.php')
```

It will return an array of the matching path strings.  You can also just use:

```
ls /home/*/public_html/images/*.php
```

or:

```
for i in /tmp/*/public_html/images/*.php;
do 
some_command "$i"
done
```

from the shell.

Comment: I believe he's doing this in the shell, not php.

Comment: @marcog, it's tagged PHP.  But it doesn't really matter.

Comment: The PHP tag might just come from the fact that he's listing .php files.

Comment: Technically, you can use PHP as a shell script, although it just feels awkward. ;)